# Effective action of interacting electron gas (Altland & Simons derivation)

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, condensed-matter, perturbation-theory

I have a question re: equation (6.6) in Altland and Simons, which claims that the effective action of an interacting electron gas takes the form
$$S\propto \sum_q \phi_q\left( \frac{\mathbf{q}^2}{4\pi}-e^2\Pi_{q}\right)\phi_{-q}.\tag{6.6}$$
What I don't understand is where the negative sign in front of the $e^2\Pi_q$ term comes from. If I follow their derivation, starting with equation (6.4), I have

$$S[\phi] = \frac{\beta}{8\pi L^d}\sum_q\phi_q\mathbf{q}^2\phi_{-q} - \text{tr}\ln\left[-i\omega + \frac{\mathbf{p}^2}{2m}-\mu+\frac{ie}{L^d}\phi\right] \tag{6.4}$$
$$=\frac{\beta}{8\pi L^d}\sum_q\phi_q\mathbf{q}^2\phi_{-q} + \text{tr}\ln\left[G_0^{-1}(\phi)-\frac{ie}{L^d}\phi\right]$$
Now, expanding the logarithm in small powers of $\phi$, we have

$$\text{tr}\ln\left[G_0^{-1}(\phi)-\frac{ie}{L^d}\phi\right] \approx \text{tr}\ln G^{-1}_0 + \frac{ie}{L^d}\text{tr}[G_0\phi] + \frac{1}{2}\frac{e^2}{L^2d}\text{tr}[G_0\phi G_0\phi]$$

where the quadratic term is **positive** because of the factor of $i^2$ that multiplied out the $-1$ in the Taylor expansion of $\ln(1+x)$.
NOTE: here I think there should actually be a $-$ sign in front of the second term because $\ln(1+x)\approx -x -\frac{x^2}{2}$ but whatever, because we don't care about this term.
Anyways. We can show that
$$\text{tr}[G_0 \phi G_0 \phi] = \frac{L^d}{2T}\sum_q\Pi_q \phi_q\phi_{-q}$$
Putting this back together with equation 6.4, shouldn't we have
$$S\propto \sum_q \phi_q\left( \frac{\mathbf{q}^2}{4\pi}+e^2\Pi_{q}\right)\phi_{-q}$$
I am not sure where the negative sign came from in this derivation.

Comment: In your first equation, shouldn't you have  $+Tr \ln(-G_0^{-1} + \frac{ie}{L^d} \phi)$? It looks to me like you're saying $\ln (-x) = -\ln x$, which would be incorrect. It also looks to me like your expansion of the logarithm might be incorrect

Comment: You are right! Thank you very much